# using dark mode in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I think the best way to change color is using the theme props or in the doc look something like this :

```
import { flavourOptions } from '../data';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={flavourOptions[2]}
    label="Single select"
    options={flavourOptions}
    theme={theme => ({
      ...theme,
      borderRadius: 0,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        primary25: 'hotpink',
        primary: 'black',
      },
    })}
  />
);
```

but, I am not stuck at figuring out how to "connect" it dark mode togggle..

Comment: Theme related changes can be connected to toggles via [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: This was helpful for me for getting react-select to honor dark mode: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4067#issuecomment-721672676

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example with tailwind css making use of the `className` and `classNamePrefix` arguments:

React usage:

```
<Select
   className="my-react-select-container"
   classNamePrefix="my-react-select"
...
```

Tailwind CSS `index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  /* .my-react-select-container {
  } */
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__control {
    @apply bg-white dark:bg-neutral-700 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-700 hover:border-neutral-400 dark:hover:border-neutral-500;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__control--is-focused {
    @apply border-neutral-500 hover:border-neutral-500 dark:border-neutral-400 dark:hover:border-neutral-400 shadow-none;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__menu {
    @apply bg-neutral-100 dark:bg-neutral-700 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-600;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__option {
    @apply text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200 bg-neutral-100 hover:bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-700 dark:hover:bg-neutral-800;
  }
  /* .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__option--is-focused {
    @apply bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-800;
  } */

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__indicator-separator {
    @apply bg-neutral-400;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__input-container,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__placeholder,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__single-value {
    @apply text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should use CSS variables to change the colors for light and dark mode. Then you could apply dark mode styles separately using CSS or Sass, like this:

Using SCSS:

```
.react-select-container {
  .react-select__control {
    background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
    border-color: var(--border-color);
    transition: none;

    &:hover {
      border-color: var(--border-color);
    }
  }

  .react-select__menu {
    background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
  }

  .react-select__option {
    background-color: var(--bg-secondary);

    &:hover {
      background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    }
  }

  .react-select__indicator-separator {
    background-color: var(--border-color);
  }

  .react-select__placeholder,
  .react-select__single-value {
    color: var(--text-primary);
  }
}
```

That's the way I did it, but if anyone find out a better way please contribute to this question!

Answer (score 1):

There are additional classes for multi-select.  This is more complete:

[image: multiselect with dark mode]

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  /* .my-react-select-container {
  } */
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__control {
    @apply bg-white dark:bg-neutral-700 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-700 hover:border-neutral-400 dark:hover:border-neutral-500;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__control--is-focused {
    @apply border-neutral-500 hover:border-neutral-500 dark:border-neutral-400 dark:hover:border-neutral-400 shadow-none;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__menu {
    @apply bg-neutral-100 dark:bg-neutral-700 border-2 border-neutral-300 dark:border-neutral-600;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__option {
    @apply text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200 bg-neutral-100 hover:bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-700 dark:hover:bg-neutral-800;
  }
  /* .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__option--is-focused {
    @apply bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-800;
  } */

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__indicator-separator {
    @apply bg-neutral-400;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__input-container,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__placeholder,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__single-value {
    @apply text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-200;
  }

    /* Multi-value container and labels */
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__multi-value {
    @apply bg-neutral-400 dark:bg-neutral-600 rounded-md;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__multi-value__label {
    @apply text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-100;
  }

  /* Multi-value remove button and SVG */
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__multi-value__remove {
    @apply bg-neutral-500 dark:bg-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-600 dark:hover:bg-neutral-800 rounded-full;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__multi-value__remove .css-tj5bde-Svg {
    @apply text-neutral-200 dark:text-neutral-400;
  }

  /* Clear and dropdown indicator */
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__clear-indicator,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__dropdown-indicator {
    @apply text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-600;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__clear-indicator:hover,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__dropdown-indicator:hover {
    @apply text-neutral-500 dark:text-neutral-500;
  }

  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__clear-indicator .css-tj5bde-Svg,
  .my-react-select-container .my-react-select__dropdown-indicator .css-tj5bde-Svg {
    @apply fill-current;
  }
}
```